# Saving Non-VSTO copy of VSTO Workbook

Tags: vb.net, excel, vsto, save

I am trying to save a ListObject from a .NET 3.5 Excel 2007 VSTO Workbook to a new sheet (done) and save that new sheet to a new workbook (done) without that workbook requiring the VSTO customization file (!!!!!).

Has anyone had any luck with this?  The only way I've had any success is just saving as a CSV file but that's not exactly acceptable in this case.  I'd rather not save to a CSV just to copy back to a XLS file.

> worksheet.SaveAs(saveDialog.FileName, Excel.XlFileFormat.xlOpenXMLWorkbook)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you do not want the new workbook file to depend or load any VSTO customization?

Try this [MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb772099.aspx) to remove VSTO customization assemblies from workbooks.

Answer (score 1):

Ok this didn't end up working for me and here's why.  The answer is still correct but I want to clarify for future users.

I have a ListObject I wanted to save in an external workbook using VSTO.  Creating a new Worksheet and using SaveAs would rename the current Workbook to that and therefore I would have to close the entire workbook to remove the Customization.

What I should have done from the beginning is this:

Create the Worksheet and populate the ListObject on said Worksheet.  Then use .Copy() with no parameters to create a new workbook.  How do i find the workbook then though?  I simply named the Worksheet Now.Ticks.ToString() and looked for any open workbook with the ActiveSheet.Name as Now.Ticks.ToString().   For this application, it doesn't need to be more in depth then that.  I the saved THAT workbook and then closed it.  Since the workbook was created with Copy it had no customizations on it and problem solved.

Comment: sounds hard. why didn't you just do... Excel.Workbook wkbk = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(params); Excel.Worksheet wksht = wkbk.Worksheets.get_Item("Sheet1"); Insert code to populate ListObject onto wksht here... wkbk.Close(true);

Comment: I believe I tried that route first, but the resulting workbook had the VSTO requirement attached to it.   I could be mistaken though.

Comment: ok so do what i said then call  the Workbook.RemoveCustomization method, on the wkbk object.